# How to use the same width for numbers in y axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I am drawing some graphs and I wanna import them in LaTex in 2 by 2 format. One of the problems is that values on the y-axis for one graph range from 1 to 6, but for another graph, those range from 1 to 200. Because of that, when I import graphs into my document, they do not look good. Is there any way to set the same width for value on the y-axis?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the y axis limits using `ax.set_ylim` or `plt.ylim`:

```
# Set axis from 1 to 200
ax.set_ylim((1,200))

# Or just set it directly - this will also act on the current axis
plt.ylim((1,200))
```

Edit: The question is about widths rather than limits.
I think making the subplots together on one figure should solve this problem.

```
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.plot(x1,y1)
.
.
plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.plot(x4,y4)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Because for the first case, it uses just one digit number and for the second case, it uses 3 digits, the y-axes in two graphs do not fit.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. I think making the subplots in one figure should solve this problem. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks @pasnik. Actually, I save each graph as a different file and import them into a LaTeX file, so I cannot use subplot. For example, suppose the width of the graph is 7 inches. For the first graph, the values shown on the y-axis are 1 to 8 (all one digit numbers). However, for the second graph, values are 100s (3 digit). Because the width of both graphs should be 7 inches, then the y-axis in the second graph move to the right compared to the first graph